# -bash: ant: command not found in mac

Tags: macos, ant

I download apache-ant-1.9.14-bin.tar.gz
(http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)

I referenced link(https://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-apache-ant-on-mac-os-x/)

I decompress in `/Users/hoon/ant/`

I try `ant -v` in terminal(`pwd = /Users/hoon/ant/apache-ant-1.9.14/bin`)

but `-bash: ant:` command not found

I don't understand.

Is there anything wrong with me?

my java -version is `java version "1.8.0_212"`

Comment: Is the bin directory in your `$PATH`?

Comment: thank you. 
I was wrongly written